# creating a data type for wrapping structures with ctypes

Tags: python, c, ctypes

So I'm learning about `ctypes` and I have a situation similar to the following:

I have a shared library with structures that implement a matrix of doubles and a matrix of complex numbers. I want to wrap both of these structures with `ctypes`. I know I can make two classes to wrap each structure, but I'm wondering if there is a straightforward way to wrap both structures with one class by specifying a data type.

For example, maybe my library `libmatrix.so` has the following source file:

```
// matrix.c

struct complex {
    double re;
    double im;
};

struct Matrix {
    int nrow;
    int ncol;
    double *data
};

struct CMatrix {
    int nrow;
    int ncol;
    complex *data
};

typedef struct complex complex;
typedef struct Matrix Matrix;
typedef struct CMatrix CMatrix;
```

After wrapping my `complex` structure, perhaps like so:

```
class complex(Structure):
    __fields__ = [("re", c_double), ("im", c_double)]
```

In python I would like to create a class `Matrix` that lets me do the following:

```
# create 2 x 3 matrix of doubles 
m = Matrix(2, 3, dtype=c_double)

# create 2 x 3 matrix of complex numbers (structure that I made)
n = Matrix(2, 3, dtype=complex)
```

I know numpy has something like this, I tried consulting the source code, but I got overwhelmed. Is there a name for this type of thing or have a reference? Any direction would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a rough example how it could be done.  Everything in Python is an object, so the data type can be passed directly and used to allocate the array.  A few overrides make the matrix easier to manipulate and display.

```py
from ctypes import *
from pprint import pformat

class Complex(Structure):

    _fields_ = (('re',c_double),
                ('im',c_double))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Complex({self.re}{self.im:+}j)'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.re}{self.im:+}j'

class Matrix(Structure):

    _fields_ = (('nrow',c_int),
                ('ncol',c_int),
                ('data',c_void_p))

    def __init__(self,row,col,dtype):
        self.nrow = row
        self.ncol = col
        self._data = (dtype * col * row)() # internal instance of allocated array
        self.data = cast(byref(self._data),c_void_p) # generic pointer to array

    # forward to the array instance
    def __getitem__(self,key):
        return self._data.__getitem__(key)

    # forward to the array instance
    def __setitem__(self,key,value):
        return self._data.__setitem__(key,value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return pformat([r[:] for r in self._data])

mc = Matrix(2,3,Complex)
md = Matrix(3,2,c_double)
mc[1][2] = Complex(1.1,-2.2)
md[2][1] = 1.5
print(mc)
print(md)
```

Output:

```
[[Complex(0.0+0.0j), Complex(0.0+0.0j), Complex(0.0+0.0j)],
 [Complex(0.0+0.0j), Complex(0.0+0.0j), Complex(1.1-2.2j)]]
[[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.5]]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, I have spent most of the day digesting it and it was really helpful. It also helped me learn more about c programming :)